# Is this upgrade error fatal?

Tags: upgrade, gtk

```
 (gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0:19389): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory

This likely means that your installation is broken.
Try running the command
  gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache
```

Get this error while upgrading and updating just checking to make sure its not going to affect the operating system and the way it runs.

Comment: Did you try running the suggested command?

Comment: The error does not look fatal or even serious.  The update is looking for a file that doesn't exist.  Run the command as the script asks:  gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache

Comment: The suggested command cannot be found even as sudo (note: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is installed)

Comment: I had to install `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev`, which is NOT automatic.

Comment: happens with 18.10 upgrade as well. No issues as of now. It's just a warning

Answer (score 5):

Running the corresponding command will often not work because the binary is not in the PATH: you need to run it with an indication of the complete path, and also to run it as root:

```
sudo /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders | sudo tee /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache
```

(may need to be adapted for your install)

More information in [this Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=640150).